# How can I easily combine two XML documents with the same parent node into one document?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I've decided there's no way to do this with SimpleXMLElements. I have been reading the PHP DOMDocument manual, and I think I could do it with iteration, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way that's not occurring to me?

Psuedocode-ish iterative solution:

```
// two DOMDocuments with same root element
$parent = new ...
$otherParent = new ...

$children = $parent->getElementByTagName('child');
foreach ($children as $child) {
   $otherParent->appendChild($child);
}
```

For clarity, I have two XML documents that both look like this:

```
    <parent>
      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels of nested XML trees possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>
      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>

</parent>
```

And I would like output like this:

```
<parent>
  {all children of both original XML docs, order unimportant, that preserves any nested XML trees the children may have}
<parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the only common node you could identify between the two files would be the root node if I take your question precisely and strict so the solution would be:

```
<doc1:parent>
    <doc1:children>...</>
    <doc2:children>...</>
</doc1:parent>
```

You wrote the order is not important, so as you can see here, doc2 comes after doc1. Example code for two SimpleXML elements `$xml1` and `$xml2` that contain both the example XML form above:

```
$doc1 = dom_import_simplexml($xml1)->ownerDocument;
foreach (dom_import_simplexml($xml2)->childNodes as $child) {
    $child = $doc1->importNode($child, TRUE);
    echo $doc1->saveXML($child), "\n";
    $doc1->documentElement->appendChild($child);
}
```

Now `$doc1` contains the document represented by this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels of nested XML trees possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>
      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>

      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels of nested XML trees possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>
      <child>
        <childOfChild>
           {etc, more levels possible}
        </childOfChild>
      </child>
</parent>
```

As you can see, the trees of both documents are preserved, only the node you describe as *same* is the root node (actually that are two nodes, too), so it's not taken over from the second document, but only it's children.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was hoping there was a way to not use iteration, but I guess there isn't if I want to stick to standards and not use DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML().

Comment: @ErikaE: Technically, it would be okay to drop the XML in there, too, but I think that's nearly the same routine and you would need to iterate over the document's element children as well to get the "innerXML".